# Get JSON value from string path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I need to extract a JSON value starting from my variable.
for example i have this json

```
const myJson = {
  "id": "someID",
  "organizations": [
    "0": {
      "id": "organizationId",
      "name": "organizationName"
    },
    "1": {
      ...
    },
    ...
  ] 
}
```

and this variable

```
var pathOfKey = ["organizations","0","id"];
```

how to get the value of 'organizationId' from my variable 'pathOfKey'?

I don't know in advance what the path to my key is but I have a variable with this information.
I need to get all the organization IDs of my array.

Comment: FYI - This is not JSON, it's a JavaScript Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
"a": {"b": "value"}
}

let tmpObj = obj;
let arr = ["a", "b"];

arr.forEach((objKey) => {
  if (tmpObj[objKey] !== undefined) {
    tmpObj = tmpObj[objKey];
  }
});

console.log(tmpObj);
```

Something like this will do the job.
Also, it can be done with a recursion function

Comment: ok it works but is it possible to get all organizationIds? i need to get all data from the organizations array, but not only in this case, I can take all specific values from multiple arrays.

Comment: One solution that comes to my mind (probably not an ideal one) is setting some special item to go execute foreach loop:  
let arr = ["a", "<starChar>", "b"];  
And then inside forEach:  
if (objKey === "<starChar>") {tmpObj.forEach()=>{}}

Comment: yes I have used this approach. I check if the element of my array is a number to instantiate a loop, but I wanted to see if there is a more functional method for this. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to iterate `pathOfKey` array and traverse the object with key in the array simultaneously.

```js
function getValueFromObject(obj, path) {
  let currentNode = obj;

  for (key of path) {
    if (!currentNode.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return null;
    }
    currentNode = currentNode[key];
  }
  
  return currentNode;
}

getValueFromObject(myJson, pathOfKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const value = pathOfKey.reduce((item, key) => item[key], myJson);
```

Comment: ok it works but is it possible to get all organizationIds? i need to get all data from the organizations array, but not only in this case, I can take all specific values from multiple arrays.